# Can't Create New Thread Using Method Call

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Problem with multithreadding.
VS2010 don't accept "sendCom(IP, com)". Error: expacted method name

```
    private void sendCom(String com)
    {

        //send command 
        int i=0;
        String IP;
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            IP = getIP(item);                
            theThreads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart( sendCom(IP, com) ));
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void sendCom(String IP, String com)
    {
        theSSHclass.RunSingleCom(IP, com);
    }
```

Comment: `ThreadStart` wraps a method to execute, the not *result* of execution.

Comment: can you post an exsample how to make it right?

Comment: Use `new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => sendCom(IP, com)));`

Comment: Note this had nothing to do with windows forms, and almost nothing to do with threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the expression

```
new ThreadStart( sendCom(IP, com) );
```

It says to call `sendCom` and pass the result to the `ThreadStart` constructor.  That's not what you want - you want ThreadStart to have a reference to the `sendCom` function, and have the new thread pass in `IP` and `com`.

The typical way to do this is like Hans Passant says:

```
var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => sendCom(IP, com)));
t.Start();
```

Here you're constructing an anonymous function, that when invoked, will call `sendCom`.  You then pass this to the new Thread.  The new thread will invoke it.

Comment: thanks, ist works fine, but the thread must be started with thethread.Start();